# Qt 5.2 compilation issue on Windows 7 (32 bit)

Tags: c++, windows, qt, compiler-construction, nmake

I'm trying to compile Qt 5.2 on my own. System is Windows 7 32-bit.

I downloaded the Qt source and unzipped it.

Then I use the Visual Studio 2010 command prompt and do

```
configure -release -opengl desktop -platform win32-msvc2010 -static
```

After a while i get

```
running configuration tests....
NMake fatal error U1077: "if" : RETURN code "0x463"
Stop.
could not find output file
```

Does anyone have an idea what happened and how I can fix it?

Comment: do you have perl installed?

Comment: yes the activePerl 5.16.3

Comment: Did you add `qtbase\bin` to PATH?

Comment: you mean my source base or? and yes path C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.0\bin added

Comment: No, I mean the build directory. It's where `qmake` ends up. I'm guessing here, I haven't built Qt in ages.

Comment: Does it compile correctly if you do:  configure -prefix %CD%\qtbase -commercial -nomake tests -opengl desktop

Comment: same error :( i only want a static build because my programs are not running on other computer with my dlls... dont understand that